# Parse HTML storage format for data

Tags: python, html, curl, html-table

I have extracted a HTML storage format markup language from a website. The information is in a tabular format as shown in the website: [image]
But after I extract the information using a curl command I get the information in terms of HTML. Please advise on how to parse this information using Python such that I can gather only the data. Maybe we can insert the data in a list like [[CALX-582 Action-Item], [CALX-736 Action-Item]......]. Are there any Python-APIs that can do that? Or is it advisable to just use REGEX and parse the required data.

```
<pre><br /></pre>
<p class="auto-cursor-target"><br /></p>
<table><colgroup><col /><col /></colgroup>
<tbody>
<tr>
<th>JIRA</th>
<th>Type</th></tr>
<tr>
<td>CALX-582</td>
<td><span>Action-Item</span></td></tr>
<tr>
<td>CALX-736</td>
<td><span>Action-Item</span></td></tr>
<tr>
<td>CALX-735</td>
<td><span>Action-Item</span></td></tr>
<tr>
<td>CALX-792</td>
<td><span>Action-Item</span></td></tr>
<tr>
<td>CALX-1563</td>
<td><span>Action-Item</span></td></tr>
<tr>
<td>CALX-1567</td>
<td><span>Action-Item</span></td></tr>
<tr>
<td>CALX-1861</td>
<td>Bug</td></tr></tbody></table>
<p class="auto-cursor-target"><br /><br /></p>
```

Comment: You can consider BeautifulSoup https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As has been mentioned you could use BeautifulSoup for this.

Not sure how you want the data but the code below will create a list of dictionaries with the keys coming from the `JIRA` column and the values from the `Type` column.

You could use other methods to put the data into other types of structures.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """
<pre><br /></pre>
<p class="auto-cursor-target"><br /></p>
<table><colgroup><col /><col /></colgroup>
<tbody>
<tr>
<th>JIRA</th>
<th>Type</th></tr>
<tr>
<td>CALX-582</td>
<td><span>Action-Item</span></td></tr>
<tr>
<td>CALX-736</td>
<td><span>Action-Item</span></td></tr>
<tr>
<td>CALX-735</td>
<td><span>Action-Item</span></td></tr>
<tr>
<td>CALX-792</td>
<td><span>Action-Item</span></td></tr>
<tr>
<td>CALX-1563</td>
<td><span>Action-Item</span></td></tr>
<tr>
<td>CALX-1567</td>
<td><span>Action-Item</span></td></tr>
<tr>
<td>CALX-1861</td>
<td>Bug</td></tr></tbody></table>
<p class="auto-cursor-target"><br /><br /></p>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

jira = soup.select('td')

data = [{jira[idx].getText(): jira[idx+1].getText()} for idx in  range(0, len(jira), 2)]

print(data)
```